# determine when unsaved Notepad file was created

Tags: windows, notepad, timestamp

I have an open notepad file on my machine which I don't recall making.  Is there a way I can determine what time and day the file was created (registry key or whatnot)?  I haven't saved it yet because I don't want to muck up any file stamps, registry entries, etc.  So, to be clear, right now, it's "Untitled - Notepad".

Comment: Just FYI, it's not a file. Files exist only on storage devices. Unless you have saved it, it's just a bunch of zeros and ones somewhere in RAM.

Comment: Good distinction...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to see what time the Notepad was launched.

Right click on the process and select **Properties...**.
[image: notepad properties in process explorer]

Comment: seems the prefetch will also hold last run data for the program http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Prefetch  An untitled notepad item, is usually unsaved, so there is no "file" yet, its not Word where autosaves, and backups and all would exist.

Comment: @Psycogeek good point, I was confused on that as well.

Comment: Thanks for all your help folks; that got me what I needed, plus related notes that'll improve my skills!

Comment: @Louis, Can Task Manager do the same thing? Or are we forced to download Process Explorer?

Comment: @Pacerier I don't see it as one of the available columns in the details pane... You don't have to use ProcessExplorer though. Seems available in the System.dll assembly, and here in PowerShell: `Get-Process | Select-Object name,starttime`